# Passing an object to a form gives me __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm just starting writing a view to update a form. When I bind an object to the form, so as to pre-populate the form with the data of the object being viewed, I get an error. I've read through the documentation and many examples and as far as I can see my code is correct, so I'm at  a loss.

view.py

```
@login_required
def entries_update(request, pk):
    journal_entry = get_object_or_404(JournalEntry, pk=pk)
    journal_entry_form = JournalEntryForm(instance=journal_entry)

    return render(request, 'journal/entries_update.html',{'journal_entry': journal_entry, 'journal_entry_form': journal_entry_form,})
```

forms.py

```
class JournalEntryForm(forms.Form):
    # This can be simpliedied to a ModelForm
    date = forms.DateField(widget=DateTypeInput())
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)
    def clean_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['date']
        #Check date is not more than 30d future
        if data > (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(30)):
            raise ValidationError('Date cannot be more than 30d future')
        if data < (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(90)):
            raise ValidationError('Date cannot be more than 90d past')
        return data
```

models.py

```
class JournalEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    TYPE = (
        ('BP', 'Bank Payment'),
        ('YE', 'Year End'),
        ('JE', 'Journal Entry')
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=TYPE,
        blank=True,
        default='0'
        )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        if self.description:
            return self.description
        else:
            return 'Journal Entry' + str(self.id)
    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Journal entries'
```

Last item in the traceback:

```
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\Journal\views.py in entries_update
    journal_entry_form = JournalEntryForm(instance=journal_entry) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
journal_entry   
<JournalEntry: Journal Entry108>
pk  
108
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/journal/entries/update/108/'>
```

Comment: `JournalEntryForm` must be a `forms.ModelForm` if you wish to use it to update existing instances

Answer (score 0):

Iain Shelvington's comment solved the issue. Changed the form to model form and now I could pass the instance.